# why the erf function works correctly, but erfc does not work

Tags: python, math

Chebyshev-Gauss Approximation was used to calculate the integral, the integral function works correctly
why the erf function works correctly, but erfc does not work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt, exp


def integral(f, a, b, n = 32):
    I = 0

    for k in range(n):
        wi = 0.5 * (b - a) * sin((2 * k + 1) * pi / (2 * n)) * pi / n
        xi = 0.5 * (a + b) + 0.5 * (b - a) * cos((2 * k + 1) * pi / (2 * n))

        I += wi * f(xi)

    return I


def erf(x):
    e_t2 = lambda t: exp(- t ** 2)
    return 2 * integral(e_t2, 0, x) / sqrt(pi)


def erfc(x):
    e_t2 = lambda t: exp(- t ** 2)
    return 2 * integral(e_t2, x, 999999) / sqrt(pi)
```

The formula for finding the integral is correct and a ready-made algorithm was used. The function erf works correctly, it makes a correct graph. But erfc always gives 0 for any value

Comment: You are taking 32 steps.  Even if x is 0, the smallest value (`999999/32`) `xi` is about 600, and `exp(-600**2)` is zero.  Your function is only meaningful for rather small values of x.

Comment: Agreeing with @TimRoberts. Compare the differences between these different invocations: `for b in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]: print(integral(lambda t: exp(- t ** 2), 1.5, b))`

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, now everything works.